# Octave(MATLAB): Error in function on some inputs

Tags: matlab, octave

I wrote the following function for my filter,

```
function filteredX=dftFilter(X,lowerBound,upperBound)
    lower=max(ceil((lowerBound/(2*pi))*length(X)), 1);
    upper=floor((upperBound/(2*pi))*length(X));
    filteredX=zeros(1,length(X));
    for int=lower:upper
        filteredX(int)=X(int);
    end
endfunction
```

If I use it for the following input, everything works correctly

```
dftFilter([3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20], (pi / 4), ((3 * pi) / 4))
dftFilter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ((3 * pi) / 4), (2 * pi)
```

but when I use it on this one (notice that the length of array is now 11 instead of 10)

```
dftFilter([2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 11, 23, 12, 34, 21, 17], 0, 2 * pi)
```

it gives an error

```
subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals.
```

on line

```
filteredX(int)=X(int);
```

I tried to emulate this process in console.

```
X = [2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 11, 23, 12, 34, 21, 17];
lower=max(ceil((0/(2*pi))*length(X)), 1);
upper=floor((2*pi/(2*pi))*length(X));
filterexX=zeros(1,length(X));
for int=lower:upper;
filteredX(int)=X(int)
end
```

and it works fine.

PS: I'm using Octave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the value of `int`, inside your loop! You will see it is not an integer one, thus you indexing the matrix, with a real number, not an integer!

Comment: doesn't max (0, 1) give 1 and not 0?

Comment: I read the code @KudayarPirimbaev, but I did a mistake. I didn't rush, sorry, edited. :) Down-voting me is not the way to go, first advice me and if I show no effort, then down-vote me! :)

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev you are missing some parentheses in the code you have in the 1st block and in the code you execute online!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53855/discussion-between-g-samaras-and-kudayar-pirimbaev)